# |= operator, possible short circuit evaluation?

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators, short-circuiting

In C++, If I have a boolean that is already true, and I perform an |= on it, it is guaranteed to still execute whatever is to the right of the operator?

For example:

```
bool myBool = true;
myBool |= someFcnThatReturnsBoolean();
```

I find that it is executing that function, but I need to know if it's explicitly guaranteed by a standard that it will be guaranteed to execute. I'd hate to run into an issue where it stops executing based on some optimization, or on certain compilers.

Comment: Yes. `|` doesn't do short circuit evaluation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bool myBool = true;
myBool |= someFcnThatReturnsBoolean();
```

would be equivalent to

```
bool myBool = true;
myBool = myBool | someFcnThatReturnsBoolean();
```

The bitwise OR (`|`) will always evaluate both operands, thus your function will always be called.

Comment: Not quite equivalent: `a |= b` will evaluate each operand once, while `a = a | b` will evaluate `a` twice.

Comment: @MikeSeymour in general yes, but in a case like this where `a` is a local variable, there's really no difference, is it ?

Comment: Indeed, if the extra evaluation has no effect, then there's no difference. But it's worth mentioning that it's not always equivalent (which might be inferred from your wording).